# Gwt. ClientBundle. Override default css style of widget

Tags: java, gwt

I use ClientBundle and CssResource interfaces. All styles, that applies as class are work:

In css: `.dialogVPanel { margin: 5px;}`

In interface: `String dialogVPanel();`

But when I try to override default css of gwt widget, it don't work (no errors, but no effect). I try like this:

```
@external .gwt-DialogBox { width: 60px;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
@external gwt-DialogBox;

.gwt-DialogBox { width: 60px; }
```

Comment: but what if I want to add style like this: 
`.messageBox .gwt-Button {}` ?

Comment: `@external` lists CSS class names that are _external_ (sic!) and should be left as-is in the stylesheet (unobfuscated); then you can use them anyway you want in your selectors, including mixing them with class names that will be obuscated. So `@external gwt-Button; .messageBox .gwt-Button { ... }` is OK (`messageBox` will be obfuscated, `gwt-Button` will be left untouched, because it's marked _external_)

Comment: just want to add my thanks to Thomas for this clear example of the use of @external, FINALLY; I've been trying to get this to work for a long time